# How to share an image with a different filename on Android?

Tags: android, android-sharing

I have a gallery which is maintained through app and didn't want to give images a `jpg` extension since I didn't want images to display in phone gallery so users cannot accidentally delete them. Filenames are something like "gall.22", "gall.381", etc. In fact, there are jpeg files.

When I share one or multiple images, they are shared with their filename which is not ending with `.jpg` and therefore cannot be opened regularly if shared to email, Viber, etc.

Is there a way to share files with a custom name, not the original one (to add just .jpg at the end of filename) and to **avoid copying file** to another file with wanted name prior sharing?

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't want images to display in phone gallery

I think you can try another way instead of rename extension, you can create the folder to store images and create file .nomedia inside this folder. MediaScaner will ignore this folder when scan and you can share image in normal way.

> to avoid copying file to another file with wanted name prior sharing

When you share a file by Uri to another app can handle directly by Uri or copy, it depends on another app handle

Comment: .nomedia will work, but we have a lot of customers already and images both on webserver as a backup (and web application) and their devices, IDK if it would be easy and nice to rename all files in next app update. And by copying I ment to copy file e.g. gall.33 to gall.33.jpg and then share that new file. Just need, in that case, to check files with jpg extension in that folder and remove them to free up the space...